# Android code for grammar based speech recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I am developing an Android App which requires speech to text conversion. Currently I have used Google voice search for this purpose but using google requires internet connection and moreover it gives highly inaccurate results for eg. when I say '1' it prints "when"..
Therefore, I want to define my own grammar such that when I give a voice command it searches the grammar defined by me to find the best possible match instead of searching the internet. Using grammar for speech recognition can be done easily for windows 8 phone but I want to know how I can make this work for Android phones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom grammar for speech recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170154/custom-grammar-for-speech-recognition)! You may find more information in that thread!

Comment: This answer describes one possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007058/restricting-speech-recognition-results-on-android/17062764#17062764

Comment: Like a duplicate answer suggest, you can definitely try [pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Kindly take a look at below codes!..

```
  **Using Intent:::**

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
            txtText.setText("");
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
```

Without Using Intent::

Step 1: Implement RecognitionListener in your class.

Step 2. Add the Below codes:

```
 private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
private Intent speechIntent=null;

/**
 * Speech Result is used to Store the Voice Commands
 */
private ArrayList<String> speechResult;


inside onCreate()  --- > 

 speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
 speech.setRecognitionListener(this);


  Trigger this after your button Click: 

       if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)) {
            if(speechIntent==null ){
                speechIntent=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
                speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
                speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
                speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,12);
                speech.startListening(speechIntent);
            }else{
                if(speech!=null){
                    speech.startListening(speechIntent);
                }
            }
        }
```

Replace the onResults link this:

```
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
speechResult = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
if(speechResult!=null){
    if(speechResult.size()>0 ){
        String command=speechResult.get(0).toString();
                 }
         }
```

}

Comment: Speech recognizer is not recognizing apostrophe, like what's your name? it doesn't recognize , please help me